# The cursor is already open..I have multiple cursors in my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SELECT_SANSTHA_DEVIANCE](@DIVISION_ID int, @ZONE_ID int, @WARD_ID int, @ELECTORAL_ID int,     
           @VASTI_ID int, @SANSTHA_ID int, @MONTH int, @YEAR int)  
  As  
    Begin
        DECLARE @ID INT  
        DECLARE @SANSTHA INT

        DECLARE @USER table(USER_ID int, DATE_OF_VISIT date, TOTAL_MARKS int, SANSTHA_ID int)  

        DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR FOR  
        Select Distinct USER_ID From INSPECTION_RATING_MASTER  

        DECLARE CUR2 CURSOR FOR  
        Select Distinct SANSTHA_ID From INSPECTION_RATING_MASTER  

        OPEN CUR1  
        FETCH CUR1 INTO @ID  
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  

            OPEN CUR2  
            FETCH CUR2 INTO @SANSTHA
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                BEGIN
                     Insert Into @USER  
                            Select Top 2 USER_ID, DATE_OF_VISIT, SUM(TOTAL) As 'MARKS', SANSTHA_ID 
                            From INSPECTION_RATING_MASTER  
                            Where USER_ID = @ID
                            And SANSTHA_ID = @SANSTHA
                            And Month(DATE_OF_VISIT) = Case When @MONTH = -1 Then Month(DATE_OF_VISIT) Else @MONTH End    
                            And Year(DATE_OF_VISIT) = @YEAR
                            Group By DATE_OF_VISIT, USER_ID, SANSTHA_ID 
                            Order By DATE_OF_VISIT Desc            
                FETCH NEXT FROM CUR2 INTO @SANSTHA                      

                END  

                FETCH NEXT FROM CUR1 INTO @ID  
            END

        Close CUR2
        DEALLOCATE CUR2

        Close CUR1  
        DEALLOCATE CUR1  

        Select D.DIVISION_NAME, Z.ZONE_NAME, 
               W.WARD_NAME, E.ELEC_COUNCILOR_NAME, V.VASTI_NAME,S.SANSTHA_NAME, UI.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UI.LAST_NAME As 'NAME', 
               Convert(Varchar,U.DATE_OF_VISIT,105) As 'DATE_OF_VISIT', '160' As 'TOTAL_MARKS', U.TOTAL_MARKS As 'MARKS_OBTAINED'  
               From @USER U
               Inner Join SANSTHA_POOL_MASTER S On U.SANSTHA_ID = S.ID
               Inner Join MASTER_DATA M On U.SANSTHA_ID = M.SANSTHA_ID And U.USER_ID = M.USER_INFO_ID
               Inner Join DIVISION_MASTER D On M.DIVISION_ID = D.ID
               Inner Join ZONE_MASTER Z On M.ZONE_ID = Z.ID
               Inner Join WARD_MASTER W On M.WARD_ID = W.ID          
               Inner Join ELEC_COUNCILOR_MASTER E On M.EC_ID = E.ID
               Inner Join VASTI_MASTER V On M.VASTI_ID = V.ID
               Inner Join USER_INFO_MASTER UI On M.USER_INFO_ID = UI.ID
               Where M.DIVISION_ID = Case When @DIVISION_ID = -1 Then M.DIVISION_ID Else @DIVISION_ID End     
               And M.ZONE_ID = Case When @ZONE_ID = 0 Then M.ZONE_ID Else @ZONE_ID End     
               And M.WARD_ID = Case When @WARD_ID = 0 Then M.WARD_ID Else @WARD_ID End     
               And M.EC_ID = Case When @ELECTORAL_ID = 0 Then M.EC_ID Else @ELECTORAL_ID End     
               And M.VASTI_ID = Case When @VASTI_ID = 0 Then M.VASTI_ID Else @VASTI_ID End     
               And M.SANSTHA_ID = Case When @SANSTHA_ID = 0 Then M.SANSTHA_ID Else @SANSTHA_ID End     
               And Month(U.DATE_OF_VISIT) = Case When @MONTH = -1 Then Month(U.DATE_OF_VISIT) Else @MONTH End    
               And Year(U.DATE_OF_VISIT) = @YEAR 

        Select D.DIVISION_NAME, Z.ZONE_NAME, W.WARD_NAME, E.ELEC_COUNCILOR_NAME, V.VASTI_NAME, S.SANSTHA_NAME, 
               UI.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UI.LAST_NAME As 'NAME', MAX(TOTAL_MARKS) - MIN(TOTAL_MARKS) As 'VARIANCE'
               From @USER U
               Inner Join SANSTHA_POOL_MASTER S On U.SANSTHA_ID = S.ID
               Inner Join MASTER_DATA M On U.SANSTHA_ID = M.SANSTHA_ID And U.USER_ID = M.USER_INFO_ID
               Inner Join DIVISION_MASTER D On M.DIVISION_ID = D.ID
               Inner Join ZONE_MASTER Z On M.ZONE_ID = Z.ID
               Inner Join WARD_MASTER W On M.WARD_ID = W.ID          
               Inner Join ELEC_COUNCILOR_MASTER E On M.EC_ID = E.ID
               Inner Join VASTI_MASTER V On M.VASTI_ID = V.ID
               Inner Join USER_INFO_MASTER UI On M.USER_INFO_ID = UI.ID
               Where M.DIVISION_ID = Case When @DIVISION_ID = -1 Then M.DIVISION_ID Else @DIVISION_ID End     
               And M.ZONE_ID = Case When @ZONE_ID = 0 Then M.ZONE_ID Else @ZONE_ID End     
               And M.WARD_ID = Case When @WARD_ID = 0 Then M.WARD_ID Else @WARD_ID End     
               And M.EC_ID = Case When @ELECTORAL_ID = 0 Then M.EC_ID Else @ELECTORAL_ID End     
               And M.VASTI_ID = Case When @VASTI_ID = 0 Then M.VASTI_ID Else @VASTI_ID End     
               And M.SANSTHA_ID = Case When @SANSTHA_ID = 0 Then M.SANSTHA_ID Else @SANSTHA_ID End     
               And Month(U.DATE_OF_VISIT) = Case When @MONTH = -1 Then Month(U.DATE_OF_VISIT) Else @MONTH End    
               And Year(U.DATE_OF_VISIT) = @YEAR 
               Group By D.DIVISION_NAME, Z.ZONE_NAME, W.WARD_NAME, E.ELEC_COUNCILOR_NAME, V.VASTI_NAME, 
                        S.SANSTHA_NAME, UI.FIRST_NAME, UI.LAST_NAME            
        --Select USER_ID, SANSTHA_ID, MAX(TOTAL_MARKS) - MIN(TOTAL_MARKS) As 'DIFF'
        --     From @USER
        --     Group By USER_ID, SANSTHA_ID;
        End
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message please

Comment: Msg 16905, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SELECT_SANSTHA_DEVIANCE, Line 22
The cursor is already open.

Comment: Try declaring the Cursor as Local - `DECLARE cursorname LOCAL...`

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data or error messages into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Or better yet: rewrite your query to **AVOID** cursors altogether!

Answer (score 0):

You are opening CUR2 within the CUR1 loop without closing/deallocating it first

Before

```
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR1 INTO @ID
```

you need to put your

```
Close CUR2
DEALLOCATE CUR2
```